# Memory usage when using binding

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

I created two simple XAML files which contain a single TextBox.

The first template uses a static text:

```
<Page xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <Grid>
        <TextBox Height="20" Width="120" Text="Static Text" />
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

The second template uses a binding for the Text property:

```
<Page xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <Grid>
        <TextBox Height="20" Width="120" Text="{Binding Path=Test}" />
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

When I load the template in a loop, the memory usage constantly increases when I use the template with the binding:

```
while (true)
{
    // Memory usage increases
    var binding = Application.LoadComponent(new Uri("/ConsoleApplication1;component/Binding.xaml", UriKind.Relative));

    // Memory usage stays constant
    //var noBinding = Application.LoadComponent(new Uri("/ConsoleApplication1;component/NoBinding.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
}
```

Any ideas how the memory usage can be constant when using bindings?

Comment: How are you measuring memory? Are you sure you are not measuring dead Binding objects uncollected by the GC?

Comment: I use ProcessExplorer to measure memory usage. If the loop runs long enough an OutOfMemoryException occurs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We solved the problem by implementing a custom *MarkupExtension*. The default *Binding* is not garbage collected until the application is shut down.